# Почему появляются файлы .manifest?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

На портативном инструментарии, в котором есть все что нужно для сборки проекта, после сборки рядом с каждой целью создается файла манифеста. Для чего они нужны?

Когда я собираю проект но только уже в visual studio таких файлов нету.

Что будет, если их удалить? как сделать так, чтобы они создавались в другом месте?

Comment: Чисто догадки, exe файл состоит из нескольких секций. Секция ресурсов наполняется с файлов ресурсов отдельным модулем. Манифест подшивается к ресурсам, "линковщик ресурсов" умеет подшивать из файла, поэтому среда для него создаёт ресурс манифест, что бы он его подшил в исполнимый модуль. Если удалить - создаст ещё раз.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а если компилятору сказать /manifest:no какие будут последствия?

Comment: Я думаю будет без манифеста. Манифест позволяет: а)запростить админ привелегии (но можно и другими способами) б)поставить подпись сертификатом (подпись ставят крупные компании как знак качества). Возможно что-то ещё. Если вам это не нужно (уверен что не нужно) - думаю можно без него.